# Windows 7 & Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I want to download Ubuntu on Windows 7 and dual boot the two but before I do there is the question, can i dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu? And if I do, does it work and is it safe for the OS?

What is the procedure to follow after downloading Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes it is safe to do. Lots of people dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu, myself included.

You can install a dual-boot version of Ubuntu from within Windows by using this installer:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

It is then a very straight-forward type of installation, typical of Windows applications. For a detailed, step by step explanation of how to install it this way, check out this link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Comment: It is relatively safe but it's still worth backing up important files before making major changes to your system